# Linear Regression Application

Tags: numerical-methods, regression, data-analysis

I have a linear equation as follows:

$B_0*x_0 + B_1*x_1 + ... + B_8*x_8 = result$

And i have about 200 different situations that are categorized into two different groups, depending on whether result is greater than or less than 1. I.e.

$B_0*x_0 + ... + B_8*x_8 = 1.34$ (for situation 1)
$$..$$
$$..$$
$$..$$
$B_0*x_0 + ... + B_8*x_8 = 0.25$ (for situation 200)

If I know the *expected* result for each situation, how could I optimize (through some sort of regression) the weights Bi to achieve close to 100% accuracy? I also know the $x_i$'s for all of the situations. Ideally, I'd like to solve for a set of $B_i$'s that would work for any set of of $x_i$'s.

Any suggestions would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Regarding the question: Do you know the $x_i$ for the $200$ samples?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've updated the problem

Comment: This looks that multilinear regression with $200$ data points and $9$ variables (the $B_i$'s).

Comment: @Asif I've posted a general approach to this. Is this sufficient or do you need elaboration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we label the RHS (results) $r_i$ and the corresponding column vector $r\in\mathbb R^{200}$ and the matrix $X$ where $X_{ij}$ is $x_j$ of the $i$-th sample ($X\in\mathbb R^{200\times 8}$), we want to find a vector $b$ such that
$$Xb=r$$
Since this is overdetermined, we must minimize the error. The usual way to do this is to solve
$$b = \mathop{\rm arg\;min}_{y\in\mathbb R^8} \|Xy-r\|_2$$
The solution to this can be found using a lot of iterative solvers (wich is numerically stable), such as LSMR, PCG or GMRES. Analytically, the solution is given by
$$X^TX b = X^T r \Leftrightarrow b = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T r = X^\dagger r$$
With the pseudoinverse $X^\dagger$. This however is numerically unstable so it shouldn't be used to actually compute $b$.

Comment: How would I go about implementing a solver such as those mentioned? Should I input the data into matlab and solve from there?

Comment: @Asif Writing the implementation in MATLAB is probably the easiest way. Note that there are plenty of working implementations out there already. MATLAB's backslash operator also does least-squares if the matrix isn't invertible, but I don't know the algorithm it uses.